# Can I use a custom initializer for a core data model object?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch, core-data

I use Core Data and have an object `ExerciseForRoutine`.  I'm currently manually creating it and then settings it's attributes, which seems to waste code.  Is there any way I can create a custom init method to handle this in one line (I know how to do around alloc/init, but core data has a different init method..)

Current Code:

```
ExerciseForRoutine *exerciseForRoutine = (ExerciseForRoutine *)[NSEntityDescription insertNewObjectForEntityForName:@"ExerciseForRoutine" inManagedObjectContext:managedObjectContext];
exerciseForRoutine.name = self.selectedExercise;
exerciseForRoutine.timeStamp = date;
exerciseForRoutine.muscleGroup = self.muscleName;
exerciseForRoutine.musclePicture = self.muscleURL;
```

ExerciseForRoutine Class

```
@class Routine;

@interface ExerciseForRoutine : NSManagedObject {
@private
}
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSDate * timeStamp;
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSString * name;
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSString * muscleGroup;
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSString * musclePicture;
@property (nonatomic, strong) Routine * exerciseToRoutine;

@end

@implementation ExerciseForRoutine
@dynamic timeStamp;
@dynamic name;
@dynamic muscleGroup;
@dynamic musclePicture;
@dynamic exerciseToRoutine;
```

Comment: You should not override init. See documentation for info [Object Life-Cycle—Initialization and Deallocation](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CoreData/Articles/cdManagedObjects.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40003397-SW2)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The classes which Xcode creates for handling core data objects should not be overridden, instead what you could do is create your own custom class which inherits from NSObject and write your methods to handle the managed object their.

Sol: You can do this with the help of the parameterized init method

Then it would look something like this

```
CoreDataHelperClass *someobj = [[CoreDataHelperClass alloc]initWithname:@"name" andTimeStamp:@"Time" andMuscleGroup:@"musclegroup" andPicture:UIImagePNGRepresentation(someimageObj)];
```

To do the above you need to add your own init method in the CoreDataHelperClass class like this

.h part of CoreDataHelperClass

```
- (id)initWithName:(NSString*)name andTimeStamp:(NSString*)timeStamp andMuscleGroup:(NSString*)group andPicture:(NSData*)imageData;
```

.m part of CoreDataHelperClass

```
- (id)initWithName:(NSString*)name andTimeStamp:(NSString*)timeStamp andMuscleGroup:(NSString*)group andPicture:(NSData*)imageData
{

//you assignment code to the core data attributes goes here

ExerciseForRoutine *obj = [[ExerciseForRoutine alloc]init];

obj.name = name;
obj.timestamp = timeStamp;

//and so on

return self;

}
```

Anyways what you could also do is pass a dictionary with the keyvalue pair get the values in your custom class or you may also pass an NSMutableArray like what ever suits your business model both will work.

You can get the values of Dictionary or Array inside your CoreDataHelperClass and assign those values to your attribute.

Hope i have got your query right if not then kindly mention the error part via comments

Comment: You should not override init for managed object. The documentation is clear. Please edit your question to accomodate it.

Comment: @Flex_Addicted: I am not stating for any sort of customization in the managed object class, i am speaking about creating your own class and managing the managed Object which i feel is quite doable and does not violate any norms of apple.

Comment: Ok, sorry... I misunderstood the answer. Cheers.

Comment: @Flex_Addicted : I have edited my answer so that things are much clearer

Answer (score 1):

I did this using awakeFromInsert and awakeFromFetch.

From Apple's documentation:

> In a typical Cocoa class, you usually override the designated initializer (often the init method). In a subclass of NSManagedObject, there are three different ways you can customize initialization —by overriding initWithEntity:insertIntoManagedObjectContext:, awakeFromInsert, or awakeFromFetch. You should not override init. You are discouraged from overriding initWithEntity:insertIntoManagedObjectContext: as state changes made in this method may not be properly integrated with undo and redo.

https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CoreData/Articles/cdManagedObjects.html

Answer (score 0):

To add to @Radix's answer, you should consider using `mogenerator` because it'll do much of that subclassing business for you.

http://rentzsch.github.io/mogenerator/

See [here](http://raptureinvenice.com/getting-started-with-mogenerator/) for a guide to set it up and have it running on XCode 5.

There's a small caveat to watch out for though: if you get an assertion failure that reads:

```
-[MOGeneratorApp setModel:] blah blah blah
```

Then you should point `mogenerator` to the `.xcdatamodel` file inside of the `.xcdatamodeld` package in your Run Script Phase, like so:

```
mogenerator -m Model.xcdatamodeld/Model.xcdatamodel -O Project/Model --template-var arc=true
```

Where `Project` is the name of your project and `Model` is the name of your model.

See https://github.com/rentzsch/mogenerator/issues/169.